# Pytest not finding all tests in subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, subdirectory

I'm having trouble getting pytest to run all my test cases in all sub directories

When I run `pytest -v -s` in the `Project` directory, it only ends up finding all the test cases in `ComponentB` and can't find `ComponentA` test cases.

Test cases run fine when I navigate to the respective component directories and run the `pytest` command. Why is pytest skipping `ComponentA` when run at the top level?

```
Project
 |-ComponentA
 |  |-srcs
 |  └-tests
 |     |-test_A_1.py
 |     └-test_A_2.py
 └-ComponentB
    |-srcs
    └-tests
       |-test_B_1.py
       └-test_B_2.py
```

Comment: You might need `__init__.py` files in the sub directories.

Comment: @pylang - it should work without the `__init__.py` in Python 3, provided all test files have different names, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: Very strange. I don't reproduce this problem. Could you try to rename folder/files and see if you find out in what condition this happens (and when it does not happen)

Comment: @pylang I've tried adding and removing `__init__.py` and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Another thing to check is that if you have a Class, it also have to follow the convention e.g. `def Test_MyClass():`

Answer (score 2):

I assume the file names in your question are just examples but check if your real file names match the conventions for [test discovery](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery):

> Pytest implements the following standard test discovery:
>
> - If no arguments are specified then collection starts from testpaths (if configured) or the current directory. Alternatively, command line arguments can be used in any combination of directories, file names or node ids.
> - Recurse into directories, unless they match norecursedirs.
> - In those directories, **search for test_*.py or *_test.py files**, imported by their test package name.
> - From those files, collect test items:
>
>   - test prefixed test functions or methods outside of class
>   - test prefixed test functions or methods inside Test prefixed test classes (without an **init** method)

Comment: Sorry thanks for catching that, the code I provided was an example, I am using the test discovery format test_*.py.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `ComponentB` or `ComponentB/tests` to [testpaths](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths) in [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) as shown below, then only `test_B_1.py` and `test_B_2.py` in `ComponentB/tests/` are run:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
testpaths = ComponentB # Here
```

Or:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
testpaths = ComponentB/tests # Here
```

```
Project
 |-pytest.ini # Here
 |-ComponentA
 |  |-srcs
 |  └-tests
 |     |-test_A_1.py
 |     └-test_A_2.py
 └-ComponentB
    |-srcs
    └-tests
       |-test_B_1.py
       └-test_B_2.py
```

And, there are 2 ways to run both `test_A_1.py` and `test_A_2.py` in `ComponentA/tests/` and `test_B_1.py` and `test_B_2.py` in `ComponentB/tests/`.

So, the 1st way is setting `testpaths` in `pytest.ini` as shown below. *This way runs tests faster than the 2nd way according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths):

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
testpaths = ComponentA ComponentB # Here
```

Or:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
testpaths = ComponentA/tests ComponentB/tests # Here
```

And, the 2nd way is not setting `testpaths` in `pytest.ini` as shown below because by default, `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` folders are found and the all tests in their folders are run. *This way runs tests slower than the 1st way:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
# testpaths = ComponentA ComponentB # Here
```

Or:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
# testpaths = ComponentA/tests ComponentB/tests # Here
```

In addition, these commands below can run both `test_A_1.py` and `test_A_2.py` in `ComponentA/tests/` and `test_B_1.py` and `test_B_2.py` in `ComponentB/tests/` according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html#specifying-which-tests-to-run):

```
pytest ComponentA ComponentB
```

Or:

```
pytest ComponentA/tests ComponentB/tests
```

Or:

```
pytest ComponentA/tests/test_A_1.py ComponentA/tests/test_A_2.py ComponentB/tests/test_B_1.py ComponentB/tests/test_B_2.py
```